# Error converting data type varchar to numeric using cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting an error message when trying to do a SUM with a varchar field, I'm getting the following error even when using Cast?

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric

SUM(ISNULL(CAST(balance-current_balance_amount /100 AS float),0)) AS bal_diff
```

Comment: What is the datatypes of `balance` and `current_balance_amount`?

Comment: Why are you storing a balance in a `varchar` column?

Comment: So after it's imported, fix the data type. Or import into a staging table and then move it into your production table properly, instead of querying on poorly imported data.

Comment: I am unable to change the data types.it gives multiple errors. my question was the one i've posted

Comment: Well if you don't fix the data type you are going to continue having problems with numeric calculations every time more non-numeric junk gets into this column. I still think your best approach should be (a) get rid of the junk in this column, (b) fix the data type, (c) fix the process that keeps putting non-numeric junk into this column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have non-numeric data in your balance column. If the data were valid, you wouldn't even need a CAST.

```
SUM(ISNULL((balance-current_balance_amount)/100 ,0)) AS bal_diff
```

From [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Implicit conversions are those conversions that occur without
>   specifying either the CAST or CONVERT function.

VARCHAR to NUMERIC or FLOAT are examples of this.

Since you are dealing with balance, which likely has decimal places and possible "$", a CAST to MONEY should fix your issue.

```
SUM(ISNULL((CAST(balance AS MONEY)-current_balance_amount)/100 ,0))
```

If you have other non-numeric data in your balance column that is still causing an issue after your CAST to MONEY, you could do a CASE statement in your SELECT

```
SUM(ISNULL(((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(balance) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CAST(balance AS MONEY) END)-current_balance_amount)/100 ,0))
```

Or even better, create a new column of type MONEY and start using that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `balance`  is a varchar field, you need to cast it to a numeric (`float` if thats what you want) datatype before trying to do the calculation:

eg/

```
SUM(
  ISNULL(
    (CAST(balance AS FLOAT)-current_balance_amount)/100
  ,0)
) AS bal_diff
```

Comment: Then you need to find the data in balance that is junk and shouldn't be there, e.g. a first pass might be close enough: `SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.table WHERE ISNUMERIC(balance) = 0;`